# Как исправить проблему с кавычками в phpstorm?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Использую ide - PhpStorm 2016.2.1 под os x. 
При редактировании php или js кода phpstorm переодически вставляет или наоборот удаляет кавычки там где это не нужно. Я пошел в настройки во вкладку "Smart keys" и отжал все чекбоксы, но это не помогло.

Демонстрация проблемы. После того как я пытаюсь вставить в строку букву i, phpstorm удаляет кавычку в конце строки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: глючная у вас какая-то система, у меня все норм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение подсказал пользователь @Alibek-kz на тостере.
Проблема оказалась из-за раскладки клавиатуры "США ПК". После замены на "США" проблема решена.